# Jquery/ Ajax: Send additional php variable to server sided script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this **select box**. The selected option is sent with ajax to a server side script.

```
<select id="main_select">
    <option selected="selected" value="50">50</option>
       <option value="100">100</option>
       <option value="150">150</option>
</select>
```

**jquery script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#main_select').change(function() {
$.ajax({
  url: "itemscript.php",
  type: "post",
  data: {
    option: $(this).val()
  },
  success: function(data) {
    $("#details").html(data);
  }
 });
 }).change();
});
```

And in the server sided script **(itemscript.php)** I get the variable from the select box like that:

```
if(isset($_POST["option"]))
{
    $itemlevel = $_POST["option"];
}
```

Now I want to extend this script to send an additional php variable called `$element` to the server sided script (itemscript.php). The `$element` variable is a part of the the current url address.

How can I send the additional `$element` variable within this jquery/ ajax script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the other data items into the data{} part, separated by commas.

Assuming that your $element data is inside an inputbox, then

HTML

```
<input id="element">
<br>
<select id="main_select">
    <option selected="selected" value="50">50</option>
       <option value="100">100</option>
       <option value="150">150</option>
</select>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#main_select').change(function() {
$.ajax({
  url: "itemscript.php",
 method: "POST",
  data: {
    option: $(this).val(),
    element: document.getElementById("element").value
  },
  .success: function(data) {
    $("#details").html(data);
  }
 });
 }).change();
});
```

In the above, $_POST["element"] will be passed to your php scripts

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot.